Permission denied to Google Cloud Secret on firebase function deploy, even with Secret Manager Admin Role
I have a Firebase project that uses SecretParam.
from firebase_functions.params import SecretParam

XYZ_PASSWORD = SecretParam('XYZ_PASSWORD')
...

I have a secret account with Secret Manager Admin role.

However, when I try to deploy the Firebase functions, it gives me this error in the log:
firebase deploy --only functions

i  functions: ensuring 3*******-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com access to secret XYZ_PASSWORD.

Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission 'secretmanager.secrets.setIamPolicy' denied for resource 'projects/*******/secrets/XYZ_PASSWORD' (or it may not exist).

The secretmanager.secrets.setIamPolicy should be available on the Secret Manager Admin role, as per the documentation.
Any suggestions why does this not work?

Solved. My GCP user, the one logged in Firebase CLI with firebase login, was missing the setIamPolicy. Adding the policy to it and redeploying solved.
